# Clarfication on binmode

Tags: perl

I'm new to Perl.

I was getting errors in my print statement: "Wide character in print"

And adding this line of code made it work

```
#binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
```

I read the doc, simply put, binmode encodes characters in a manner that the platform can understand.

Without it, the platform may be expecting the characters to mean something else because it is using a different encoding.

Or is my understanding of binmode off ?

Is there a way with perl to find out what encoding the platform is using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use open ':std', ':locale';
```

can help. Doesn't work on all systems, though.

Comment: it did help, i got an error saying that my character does not map to ascii :)

Comment: If it used ASCII, it probably didn't work as well as it should have X_X Or is that what you were expecting?

Comment: "X_X" is an emoticon, not an encoding. No idea what encoding you should have gotten. Usually UTF-8 on linux boxes.